# MSI Afterburner does not apply fan curve if closed?

Tags: fan, msi-afterburner

I made a fan curve but if I close MSI Afterburner it goes back to the old settings.

How do I get them to work from start without opening MSI Afteburner?

Comment: the application stays running, minimise it. Use Apply after making changes. Make a profile. Make sure you set  'Apply overclocking at system startup' and enable 'Start with Windows' . if the program had a seperate service item (some do) then that is different, this does not, the program stays running minimised.

Comment: @Psycogeek - Does it at least minimise to tray? Also you should add that as an answer :)